# Using memset with pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memset

How do I `memset` an array using a pointer to that array?

```
int *A, n;

printf("\n Enter the size of array : ");
scanf("%d",&n);

A = (int*) malloc(sizeof(*A) * n);

int i = 0;

memset(*A,5,n * sizeof(*A));

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d ", A[i]);
```

Comment: The first argument to `memset()` must be a pointer. `*A` is an `int`, `A` is a pointer.

Comment: You should have gotten a warning from that code. If not, turn up the warning level of your compiler.

Comment: yes indeed i received an error which is: warning: passing argument 1 of 'memset' makes pointer from integer without a cast
and also: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'int'

Comment: Just change the first argument to `A`.

Comment: BTW: [dont cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: but it still doesn't initialize the array and just gives a garbage value, this is the result btw:
 Enter the size of array : 10
84215045, 84215045, 84215045, 84215045, 84215045, 84215045, 84215045, 84215045, 84215045, 84215045

Comment: You're setting all the bytes to 5, not the integers.  The 4 byte ints will have the hex value 0x05050505, which is 84215045 in decimal.

Comment: Hey, doesn't anyone wanna sum all this up in a nice, tidy "answer?"  **:-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't emit warnings for no reason:

> ```
> warning: passing argument 1 of 'memset' makes pointer from integer without a cast
> expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'int'
> ```

This means that you are not passing the right type to the first argument of `memset()`, which indeed wants a *pointer*, while you are passing an *integer*.

Your pointer `A` is fine as is, dereferencing it (`*A`) is not needed and is wrong, the correct call is:

```
memset(A, 5, n * sizeof(*A));
```

More importantly though, this is not what you want to do! If you think the above sets all the elements of the allocated array to `5` that's not the case. Instead, `memset()` sets *every single byte* to `5` (see the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html)). Since an `int` is more than one byte (usually 4), this will fill your array with the value `0x05050505` (decimal `84215045`) instead of `5`.

In order to set every element to `5` you'll need a `for` loop:

```
int i = 0; 
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    A[i] = 5;
```

Finally, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc):

```
A = malloc(sizeof(*A) * n);
```

Comment: So that's why it wont set all element to 5 even if I remove the indirection. Thank you so much for your help @Marco Bonelli. It helped me a lot to understand what I am doing.